# How to get param without using "?" from url in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cakephp, parameter-passing, cakephp-3.0

In this project, I have to get param from url in cakephp 3.x as the project documentation.

But it's strange given url in doc, it's like that (New param passing url)

> www.example.com/param_name/param_value

I can get param value in old method parameter passing url like that below.

> www.example.com?param_name=param_value

But in newer method using "/" instead of "?" and "=", I don't know how to get that param value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/param_name/:param_value',['controller' => 'YourController','action' => 'view'])-> setPass(['param_value']);
```

in  src/Controller/YourController.php

```
public function view($param_value)
{
   echo $param_value;
}
```

Comment: in rout.php declare like that mean, is that ":" full column is need in url before param_value???
/param_name/:param_value